# python sum right and left components in list

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list:

```
key: [[1, 3, 4, 5, 3]]
```

I need to get list like

```
key: [[6, 5, 8, 7, 6]]
```

How can I do that with Python?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ????

Comment: i try to get new lis by summing right and left adjacent components from first list

Comment: That "explanation" does not seem to explain. Please clarify more. Also, that is not a list of numbers, it is a list containing a list of numbers. Is that really what you have?

Comment: Would have been easier to understand if you actually tried to solve it, with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 3]
>>> new_list = []    
>>> for i,x in enumerate(my_list):
...     if i==0:
...         new_list.append(my_list[-1] + my_list[i+1])
...     elif i==len(my_list)-1:
...         new_list.append(my_list[0] + my_list[i-1])
...     else:
...         new_list.append(my_list[i-1] + my_list[i+1])
... 
>>> new_list
... [6, 5, 8, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use  list comprehension:

```
[a[i-1]+(a+a[:1])[i+1] for i in range(len(a))]
```

this works because:

- `a[-1]` returns the last element of the list
- `a+a[:1]` appends the first element of the list to the end

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach:

```
from operator import add

list(map(add, key[1:]+key[:1], key[-1:] + key[:-1]))
# [6, 5, 8, 7, 6]
```